# Option analysis

Tags: options, risk, risk-neutral-measure, self-study

Assume zero dividend and that the strike price for a European call option on a stock at a fixed  maturity **T** and strike price **K** is given by **C(K)**.Suppose that $C(K)=e^{-k}$ for all $K\geq 0$ ,then, I want to find out the following

1.What must the present value of stock be?

2.What is the risk neutral probability that the stock price will lie in the interval [5,10] at maturity

3.What is the present value of contract that pays $X^2$ at maturity if the stock price at maturity is **X**

Solution:
 I don't know answer to this question. I know  Black-Scholes formula, binomial option pricing,VaR, mean-variance portfolio optimisation and black-litterman model.How should I proceed to answer these questions?

Comment: What do you mean "the strike price for a European call option" and strike price $K$? Is the first strike price just the price? Is the interest rate also zero?

Comment: @Gordon You are correct.Assume zero interest and strike price of call is the price of the call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(1)**. We consider a call option with strike $K=0$. Then $S_0=C(0)=1$.

**(2)**. We assume zero interest rate. Then, for any $K\ge 0$,
\begin{align*}
1_{S_T \ge K} &=\lim_{\varepsilon \rightarrow 0}\frac{(S_T-K)^+ - (S_T-K-\varepsilon)^+}{\varepsilon}.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
P(S_T \ge K) &= -\frac{\partial C(K)}{\partial K}\\
&= e^{-K}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
P(5 \le S_T < 10) &= P(S_T \ge 5) - P(S_T \ge 10)\\
&= e^{-5}-e^{-10}.
\end{align*}

**(3)**. Note that 
\begin{align*}
S_T^2 = 2\int_0^{\infty}(S_T-K)^+ dK.
\end{align*}
Then
\begin{align*}
e^{-rT} E\big(S_T^2\big) &= 2\int_0^{\infty}e^{-rT}E\big((S_T-K)^+\big) dK\\
&=2\int_0^{\infty} C(K) dK\\
&=2\int_0^{\infty} e^{-K} dK\\
&=2.
\end{align*}